Databricks Generating Error: AnalysisException: [ErrorClass=INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE] Missing cloud file system scheme
When I attempt to create or save a table to a location in my Azure Datalake Gen 2 using example  code:
%sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS events USING parquet OPTIONS (path "/mnt/training/ecommerce/events/events.parquet");

I get the error:

[RequestId=xxxx-xxxx-6789-8u98-de33192c16e0
ErrorClass=INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE] GenerateTemporaryPathCredential
uri /mnt/training/ecommerce/events is not a valid URI. Error message:
INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE: Missing cloud file system scheme.

I did some research and came across the following suggestion from Databricks:

In Databricks, when reading data from cloud storage like AWS S3, Azure
data lake Storage, or Google Cloud Storage, you must include the
scheme corresponding to the cloud storage.

I appreciate that is a correct suggestion, however I have mounted the ADLS Storage account with Databricks, and I'm able to read files from the ADLS account using df = spark.read.csv("/mnt/training/ecommerce/events/events.csv", inferSchema=True, header=True)

Any thoughts?
I attempted the solution suggested by @Bhavani, but unfortunately it didn't work.
I added and a new External Location as suggested:

When I try and create a table using the mounted drive I get the same error:

Just to show the that drive is mounted see the below image:

The crazy thing is, I can read from the mounted drive, see image:

One last update to show you that the connection to ADLS Gen mounted drive is successful, see image. So, I'm not sure why I'm still getting the error:


INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE] GenerateTemporaryPathCredential uri /mnt/files/Iris.parquet is not a valid URI. Error message: INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE: Missing cloud file system scheme.

When working with Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 in a Synapse or Databricks environment, you need to specify the scheme (abfss:// for ADLS Gen2). You have provided mounted path, that may be the reason to get above error. Instead of mounting ADLS Gen2 account you can follow below procedure:
Grant Storage blob data contributor role to Azure databricks managed identity. Go to Catalog page in databricks workspace click on + Select Add an external location as shown below:

Configure details while creating a new external location as shown below:

Create the external location. After successful creation of external location, you will be able to create table using below code:
%sql
CREATE  TABLE  IF  NOT  EXISTS events USING  parquet  OPTIONS (path  "abfss://<containerName>@<storageAccountName>.dfs.core.windows.net/<filepath>");


You can query table successfully as shown below:

update:
You can use below code to create table with mounted storage account:
%sql
CREATE TABLE events1 AS
SELECT
  *
FROM
  read_files(
    '/mnt/<mountName>/<pathToParquetFile>/Iris.parquet',
    header => "True"
  ); 

It will create table successfully.

Hi @Bhavani, thanks for getting in touch. I will try your suggestion. However, I've never had to do anything like this before. I didn't get this error when I created a Databricks Instance in May 2024. I created a new Databricks Instance a few days ago and ever since creating the new Databricks Instance I'm getting this error. Has Databricks made some fundamental changes?

@Patterson, I updated my answer, can you check once?

Hi @Bhavani, thanks for your update. I will check it out shortly and let you know how I get on. Thanks

Hi @Bhavani, I have updated the question. I tried your suggestion however it failed. Can you let me know if I'm missing something?

Use path in abfss://@.dfs.core.windows.net/ format while creating table as mentioned in my solution, if you want to use mounted path then try with updated solution.

Hi @Bhavani, thanks again for getting in touch. I am now able to create a table using 'abfss://@.dfs.core.windows.net/'. However, I'm getting a new error. Therefore, I think I will to submit a new question - may be you can help me with the new question. Thank you

I was facing the same issue too, then I tried this and it worked for me.

You need to create an Access Connector for Unity Catalog in the Azure portal.
Then assign the Storage Blob Data Contributor role to this connector on your Azure Storage account.
Once done unity Catalog will have the required permissions to access the storage and you can create an external location under catalog in databricks pointing to the storage.( Make sure that you have created a storage credential(under catalog) and provided resource id of the connector as Access connector ID)
Test connection

If success, you would be able to create a table :
%sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS...
LOCATION 'abfss://l1-@.dfs.core.windows.net//'
